# Deleting Cells Range From Column Based On Header

Tags: excel, vba

Just a note, I am new to VBA

I have a number of columns. If any column has the header "X", I want it to clear rows 10 - 20 from that column. I know I have to create a function but I cannot figure out what the function is. The function and the loop are below for you to see.

Thanks for any assistance

```
Public Function ColumnLettersFromRange(rInput As Range) As String
    ColumnLettersFromRange = Mid(ActiveCell.Address, 2, InStrRev(ActiveCell.Address, "$") - 2)
End Function

dim RowDelete
Set RowDelete = Range("A9:Z9")
For Each cell in RowDelete
    if cell.value = "X" then (ColumnLettersFromRange & "10:" & 
    ColumnLettersFromRange & 20).clear
Next Cell
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this will do what you want to do (no need to create function)

```
Sub test1()
Dim RowDelete As Range, cell As Range
Set RowDelete = Range("A9:Z9")
    For Each cell In RowDelete
    If cell.Value = "X" Then Range(cell.Offset(1, 0), cell.Offset(11, 0)).Clear
    Next cell
End Sub
```

if you want use function and stick to your code the try (your code modified to work). you hadn't supplied argument `rInput` to the function and encompassed resulting string with `Range(...)`.

```
Public Function ColumnLettersFromRange(rInput As Range) As String
    ColumnLettersFromRange = Mid(rInput.Address, 2, InStrRev(rInput.Address, "$") - 2)
End Function


    Sub test2()
    Dim RowDelete as Range, cell As Range
    Set RowDelete = Range("A9:Z9")
    For Each cell In RowDelete
        If cell.Value = "X" Then Range(ColumnLettersFromRange(cell) & "10:" & ColumnLettersFromRange(cell) & 20).Clear
    Next cell
    End Sub
```

Comment: When I try your second method, I keep getting a Compile Error at the first use of "cell" in the if statement. "ByRef arguement type mismatch"

Comment: Second method (your) will also work Declare both (`RowDelete` and `Cell`) as Range. don't let your effort to waste and learn more

Comment: Sorry, in Your  function you used `ActiveCell`. Replace that with `rInput` (i.e. the argument supplied) and your code will work..

Comment: do you mean 2nd (your) method? 1st method has already been working as per your previous comment.

Comment: Both methods work. I think i did not define cell as a range. Thank you very much. I have been struggling with this problem.

Comment: Welcome, You made my day. You may pl accept the answer, if it solves your problem by clicking the accept tick mark. This is to keep yourself adhered to SO spirit and also for future readers reference. and you have done some good work as new to VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastColumn As Long, i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Let us assumne that headers appear in row number 1. Find the last column of row number 1
        LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For i = 1 To LastColumn

            If .Cells(1, i).Value = "Clear" Then
                .Range(.Cells(10, i), .Cells(20, i)).ClearContents
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]

**Note:**

- `.Clear` clear both values & formattings
- `.ClearContents` clear only values